# Can you identify the Xbox 360 battery pack connector?

Tags: pcb, batteries, connector, identification

This is the contact used on the Xbox 360 battery pack.  Is it a custom part that was made for Microsoft or is it an off-the-shelf part?

If it is a custom part is there anyway I can replicate it short of sending it off to China?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @LeonHeller sure, but why can't we leave the question as an identification question. Finding connectors so that hobbyiest can use surplus/refurb batteries for commodity products seems very much on-topic.

Comment: It is not for repairs.  Its for a modified controller power supply I am building

Comment: ...then it's *even more* on topic ;-)

Comment: are you building the controller or battery? Which side of the connector are you interested in?

Comment: The battery side. So I need the part pictured

Comment: Just help him hack his controller thing...FWIW, I've never seen that as a standard connector. :\

Comment: @Leon Heller: not about …
consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, **except when designing these products or modifying their electronics for other uses** - seems alright here =P

And for Jonny, do you have a microscope? I had a similar issue with what turned out to be a Molex connector where I couldn't find anything on the web, but with a microscope finally found the serial number on the part

Comment: I do have a microscope.  I will check the part for any identifiers in obscure places.  At the moment the only ones I can see are the 3 and C on the bottom.

Comment: Its very unlikely that Microsoft got a custom part made for this. While I'll bet this is something that exists and is available on the market, it's possible that it is unusual enough to require bulk purchase (thousands of pieces). You could look towards third party battery suppliers for the xbox for hints, or maybe cannibalize one from an old battery and just connect up wires to it. Having dimensions of the connector (overall size, pin pitch) would be useful information if someone has used it before in another context an may be able to identify it.

Comment: @JonnyFlowers Have you find this connector? Could you solve this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can find the male connector apparently.
http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=2031+203470&Ntk=gensearch&Ntt=battery+connector&Ntx=mode+matchallpartial

This connector can easily be improvised. If you have a hot glue gun you may cast the connector using bits of metal. I've made a few connectors out of silicone, and they work quite well. Be creative :D

Comment: On your link I only see connectors with 2, 3, 4 or 5 connections. The image shows 6 connections. Can you add a direct link to the product you mean?

Comment: [Here](http://uk.farnell.com/bourns/70aaj-6-m0/modular-battery-contact-6-way-3a/dp/3173630) is a link to a 6 contacts connector. The problem is that is a male and you need a female connector, but as I said you should be able to improvise one that would work.

Comment: Hmm .. it seems they also have the female connector [here](http://uk.farnell.com/bourns/70adh-6-fl0/modular-battery-contact/dp/1748684). Beware that you have to pay extra 15$ for delivery, if you're outside US. Also, the picture is misleading, the connector has 6 contacts. Ask for assistance from Farnell.

Comment: Only thing left to do is check the dimensions match the ones on the controller.  The other solution would be to have a thicker PCB sit on top and act as the part